# include and get information using HTTP methods( GET and POST)

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, struts, http-method

I am using Java, Struts1, tomcat6

I have this scenario,

I need to give user LogIn credentials embedded within URl when user hit the URL of application

Like when user enters

```
localhost:8080\myApplication
```

I need to embed credentials in URL like

```
localhost:8080\myApplication?login=myName&password=myPassword
```

How can I do this?

and how can I retrieve this information later?

Also how can I send this logIn information using POST instead putting it in URL?

and also how can I retrieve this 'POST' information later?

All the help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Embed credentials, you can achieve in different ways. e.g JSP, javascript

you can use request.getParameter to retrieve them. does not matter get or post

Comment: Could you please give some example ?